# Prestashop 1.7.0.3-1.7.0.2 Fresh Install 403 Error

Tags: prestashop, http-status-code-403, fileinfo, prestashop-1.7

I have problem with installation of Prestashop 1.7.0.3 and 1.7.0.3

First, I tried to install prestashop by softaculous in my hosting, I did install 1.6.1.10, but when I tried to install 1.7.0.2 or 1.7.0.3 by softaculos I got error that saying "Required PHP extension not found : fileinfo". Then I tried upload files by ftp and install but I got 403 error this time.

I tried to set folders permission to 777 and to add .htaccess file which contains Options FollowSymLinks according to some suggests on the prestsop forum, but it still doesn't work.

Is it about my hosting settings or something related with fileinfo extension ?

Answer (score 2):

Please check your php.ini file and check that the `fileinfo.so` or `php_fileinfo.dll` is activated (depending on your server platform and version).

There should be a line similar to

> extension=fileinfo.so

After that try installing PrestaShop 1.7 and it should work without any issue.

For more details check http://build.prestashop.com/news/prestashop-1-7-faq/#what-are-system-requirements-for-v17

Comment: Thanks for answer, i am out now, i will. But since i am using reseller it's not up to me to change settings unfortunately. i will try PHP.ini in root folder maybe it will work. By the way when i checked phpinfo file php_fileinfo was disabled.